# Solving Complex Number Equation

Tags: complex-numbers

Let $z = a + ib , z^* = a - ib$

I need to find all possible solutions to $2z=(z^*)^2$

$(z^*)^2 = (a^2 - b^2) -i2ab$

$2z = 2a + i2b$

$\implies 2a + i2b = a^2 -b^2 -ia2b$
$\implies  a^2 - b^2 -i2ab - 2a - i2b = 0$
$\implies  a(a -i2b - 2) - b(b + i2) = 0$

I found solution to the above equation $z = 0$. However, I do not know how to find the rest of the solutions from here.

Comment: Alternatively, you could use polar coordinates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should separate the real and imaginary parts of your equation, keeping in mind that $a,b$ are real.  So from $a^2-b^2-2iab-2a-2ib=0$ you go to $$a^2-b^2-2a=0\\-2iab-2ib=0\\ab+b=0$$  and solve the first and third as a pair of simultaneous equations.

Comment: I don't understand why I should separate the real and imaginary parts. I just started learning the Complex system.

Comment: I see ... I need to make both the real and imaginary parts equal to 0 (as by definition).

Comment: @0xFF, do you know, $a+ib=c+id\iff a=c,b=d$. Now $0=0+i0$ i.e., $c=d=0$

Comment: @oxFF:  two complex numbers are equal precisely when the real and imaginary parts are both equal.  In particular, the origin of the complex plane is $0+0i$.  So if you wanted to solve $z^2=i$, you could write $z=a+bi, z^2=a^2+2abi-b^2=i$, so $a^2-b^2=0, 2ab=1$ and solve these two.

Comment: Thanks, I comprehend it now.